# How can I auto-equalize the width of columns whose contents are similar?

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns, options

Assume that we have a table and we want LaTeX to automatically determine its columns' width provided that column widths are equal. Such a problem can be solved by defining a new column type as follows: `\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }`. However, when using such command, LaTeX will make column widths equal, but this may result in suboptimal output like this:

[image]

Which is generated using the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}


\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedRight } X } % left justified
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X } % centered
\newcolumntype{R}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedLeft } X } % right justified
\newcolumntype{J}{ >{ \arraybackslash \justifying } X } % justified
\renewcommand \tabularxcolumn [1] { >{ \centering } m{#1} }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedRight } m{#1} }
\newcolumntype{S}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } m{#1} }
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedLeft } m{#1} }
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \justifying } m{#1} }
\usepackage{multirow}



\begin{document}



\begin{table*}[]



    % Table options
    \caption{Elasticity Values}
    \label{table:PV_mod_STC_comp2}

    % Center the table
    \centering

    % Stretch the table (vertically)
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}


        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{ D{2.6cm}@{\quad} |C|C|C|C }



            \toprule


            \multirow{2}{*}{
                                \textbf{Customer type}
                            } & 
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{
                                    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Set 1}}
                                }
            &
            \multicolumn{2}{|c}{
                                \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Set 2}}
                            }
            \\



            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{|c}{}
            \\
            \Xhline{0.2 mm}


            \textbf{Residential} &
            $-0.09$ to $-0.5$ &
            $-0.12$ to $-1.56$ & $1$ & $2$
            \\
            \Xhline{0.2 mm}


            \textbf{Commercial} & $-0.019$ to $-0.25$ & $-0.44$ to $-0.97$ & $3$ & $4$
            \\
            \Xhline{0.2 mm}


            \textbf{Industrial} & $-0.005$ to $-0.14$ & $-0.34$ to $-5.48$ & $5$ & 
            $6$
            \\



            \bottomrule



        \end{tabularx}



\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

An optimized code should result in something like this:

[image]

Which is generated by replacing the last two columns with a constant width of 1cm each. However, I want LaTeX to automatically make the last two columns small (because their contents are small) while forcing both columns to be equal. In other words, I want to define a new column type, say its name is `NewCol`, and use it in the table command `\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{ D{2.6cm}@{\quad} |C|C| NewCol|NewCol }`. `NewCol` here should result in columns of equal widths but different in size from the column type `C`. The widths of both `NewCol` and `C` should be aumatically determined according to the contents of columns and the allowable length defined in the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution measures the combined columns, then uses those widths for the tabular.  The drawback is that you have to enter the data twice.  Note that the title of Set 2 is wider than the data.

I made a number of gratuitous changes, mostly to simplify the code.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{multirow}
% none of the above are used here

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{array}% already loaded
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{ >{\hfil} m{#1} }
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{ >{\hfill} m{#1} }
\newcommand{\bigstrut}{\rule[\dimexpr -\arraystretch\dp\strutbox-1ex]{0pt}{0pt}%
  \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \arraystretch\ht\strutbox+1ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[]
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}% measure set 1
  $-0.09$ to $-0.5$\\
  $-0.12$ to $-1.56$\\
  $-0.019$ to $-0.25$\\
  $-0.44$ to $-0.97$\\
  $-0.005$ to $-0.14$\\
  $-0.34$ to $-5.48$
\end{tabular}}
\sbox1{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}% measure set 2
  1\\
  2\\
  3\\
  4\\
  5\\
  6
\end{tabular}}
    % Table options
    \caption{Elasticity Values}
    \label{table:PV_mod_STC_comp2}
    % Center the table
    \centering
    % Stretch the table (vertically)
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{ D{2.7cm}@{\quad} |C{\wd0}|C{\wd0}|C{\wd1}|C{\wd1}}
            \toprule
            \bigstrut\textbf{Customer type} &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bigstrut\textbf{Set 1}} &
            \multicolumn{2}{|c}{\bigstrut\textbf{Set 2}} \\
            \midrule
            Residential & $-0.09$ to $-0.5$   & $-0.12$ to $-1.56$  & 1 & 2 \\
            \midrule
            Commercial  & $-0.019$ to $-0.25$ & $-0.44$ to $-0.97$  & 3 & 4 \\
            \midrule
            Industrial  & $-0.005$ to $-0.14$ & $-0.34$ to $-5.48$  & 5 & 6 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: If you use booktabs, please remove all those vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? I used `>{\hsize=xₖ\hsize}X` to adjust the widths of `X` columns, the condition on the `xₖ` coefficients being that their sum is equal to the number of X columns (this works as a system of barycentric coordinates):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\captionsetup{skip=6pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedRight } X } % left justified
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering\hsize=1.6\hsize} X } % centered
\newcolumntype{y}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering\hsize=0.4\hsize} X } % centered
\newcolumntype{R}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedLeft } X } % right justified
\newcolumntype{J}{ >{ \arraybackslash \justifying } X } % justified
\renewcommand \tabularxcolumn [1] { >{ \centering } m{#1} }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedRight } m{#1} }
\newcolumntype{S}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } m{#1} }
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedLeft } m{#1} }
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \justifying } m{#1} }
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[]
    % Table options
    \caption{Elasticity Values}
    \label{table:PV_mod_STC_comp2}
    % Center the table
    \centering
    % Stretch the table (vertically)
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{ D{2.6cm}@{\quad} |C|C|y|y }
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{
                                \textbf{Customer type}
                            } &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{
                                    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Set 1}}
                                }
            &
            \multicolumn{2}{|c}{
                                \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Set 2}}
                            }
            \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{|c}{}
            \\
            \Xhline{0.2 mm}
            \textbf{Residential} &
            $-0.09$ to $-0.5$ &
            $-0.12$ to $-1.56$ & $1$ & $2$
            \\
            \Xhline{0.2 mm}
            \textbf{Commercial} & $-0.019$ to $-0.25$ & $-0.44$ to $-0.97$ & $3$ & $4$
            \\
            \Xhline{0.2 mm}
            \textbf{Industrial} & $-0.005$ to $-0.14$ & $-0.34$ to $-5.48$ & $5$ &
            $6$
            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even though the code does the job, it is still not general, that is, any change in the number of `C` columns means that the commands in the preamble must also be changed so that `\hsize` sum to the new number of `C` columns. For multiple tables, this solution will no longer be valid and many tables will not have their columns width equalized.

Answer (score 1):

`tabularx` X columns (and `tabulary` which is closer to what you ask for), like standard tabular `p` columns are designed for allowing *line breaking* within a column to a specified or calculated width, but you almost never want automatic line breaking in tables of numeric data. A standard `tabular` l,r,c column automatically adjusts to the width of the column content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}


\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

\begin{table*}

% Table options
\caption{Elasticity Values}
\label{table:PV_mod_STC_comp2}

% Center the table
\centering

% Stretch the table (vertically)
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}


\begin{tabular}{>\bfseries rcccc }
           \toprule
Customer type&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Set 1}}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Set 2}}\\
\midrule
Residential&
            $-0.09$ to $-0.5$ &
            $-0.12$ to $-1.56$ & $1$ & $2$
            \\
\midrule
 Commercial & $-0.019$ to $-0.25$ & $-0.44$ to $-0.97$ & $3$ & $4$
            \\
\midrule
Industrial & $-0.005$ to $-0.14$ & $-0.34$ to $-5.48$ & $5$ & 
            $6$
            \\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `tabulary`. The width of `tabulary` columns is proportional to the natural width of the longest entry in each column. Here, you don't calculate any thing manually. The allowed headers are `LCJR`, the three `L,C,R` are what their names suggest and `J` is like the normal `p`, all in CAPITALS.

Notes:

- When using `\multicolumns`, the width of the combined columns should
  not exceed the natural width of their separate counterparts. Observe
  the `\makebox[.7em]{$1$}` I used to increase the width a bit. Also,
  normal letters `c,l,r,p` are used for combined columns.
- To increase the height of first row a simple
  `\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{1cm}}` can do this.
- Finally, vertical rules shouldn't be used with `\toprule` or `\bottomrule`, these create a small gap under/above the horizontal line.

-

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell,tabulary}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}    
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}    % [ ] Table options
  \caption{Elasticity Values}
  \label{table:PV_mod_STC_comp2}    
  \centering                                                % Center the table    
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % Stretch the table (vertically)
  \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ R|C|C|C|C}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \textbf{Customer type}\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{1cm}}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Set 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Set 2}}\\
    \hline\textbf{Residential} & $-0.09$  to $-0.5$  & $-0.12$ to $-1.56$ & \makebox[.7em]{$1$} & $2$\\
    \hline\textbf{Commercial}  & $-0.019$ to $-0.25$ & $-0.44$ to $-0.97$ & $3$ & $4$   \\
    \hline\textbf{Industrial}  & $-0.005$ to $-0.14$ & $-0.34$ to $-5.48$ & $5$ & $6$   \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
  \end{tabulary}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]